# Spring form ModelAttribute field validation to avoid 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: java, spring, http-status-code-400, modelattribute

I've got an `ArticleFormModel` containing data sent by normal `html form` which is injected by Spring using `@ModelAttribute` annotation, i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView acceptEdit(@ModelAttribute ArticleFormModel model, 
    HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult errors)
{
    //irrelevant stuff
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine up to some point. The problem is that the `ArticleFormModel` contains a `double` field (`protected`, set using normal setter). Everything works fine as long as data sent by user is a number. When they type a word, all I get is `400 Bad Request Http Error`.

I've already registered a `WebDataBinder` for this controller

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) throws ServletException
{
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

where `validator` is an instance of a custom class implementing `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface
but I don't know what to do next. I'd like to be able to parse the model, get valid HTTP response and display error message in the form. The `initBinder()` method is called and I can call `validator.validate()` from it but it doesn't change the error (for that wrong data).

I'm aware that I could use a setter to parse the string, check if it's a number, if not, store that info in a variable, then retrieve that variable during validation, but that seems to be too much work. There has to be an easier way to force a type on the field without getting an error. Also, the issue is in data binding, not validation, so I feel that it should be placed in the respective code layer.

I was also thinking about implementing `java.beans.PropertyEditor` and calling `binder.registerCustomEditor()`, but I'm lacking a reliable knowledge source.

Client-side validation (checking if data is number via JavaScript) isn't a possibility.

**TL;DR:**

How can I force a field to be of specific type for a `@ModelAttribute` item without getting `400 Bad Request Http Error`?

Comment: Show your `ArticleFormModel` class.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis It's a normal Java Bean containing auto-generated getters and setters and an empty constructor. It extends a `Hibernate` entity. The field I'm talking about is `protected double price`. Everything works fine as long as `form` item for `price` contains only digits.

Comment: This is expected Spring behavior. If you enter an invalid format (ex. `"3.14abc"` which isn't a double), then that's a Bad Request, Invalid Syntax error. You can always put `@RequestParam` for each form field and parse them/handle errors yourself. If you're going to use `@ModelAttribute`, you have to adapt to Spring's behavior.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I understand that, but I'd like to show the user a form with error messages (preferably using `<form:error>` instead of an error page. Is this possible without handling error pages?

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way and it is impossible with `@ModelAttribute`. If your client is html, use something like `<input type="number"` .../>`. Unless you change your field to `String` and use some either custom or existing annotation to validate it to a number. You will then have to cast the String when you need to use it as a double.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `<form:errors>` for a binding error.

It looks like this:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView acceptEdit(@ModelAttribute ArticleFormModel model, 
    BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request)
{
  if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    // error handling code goes here.
  }
  ...
}
```

`errors` parameter is needed to be placed on the right after the model.

See below for details (Example 17.1):

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods

jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="articleFormModel" ... >
  ...
  <form:errors path="price" />
</form:form>
```

message properties file:

```
typeMismatch.articleFormModel.price=customized error message
```

Comment: I'd never think that the order of arguments would matter and that `BindingResults` had to go right after `@ModelAttribute`. Thanks for that, now it's working perfectly!

Comment: For the records, it works because you used a primitive type. I had the same issue with a java.util.Date attribute and I'm still getting 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @Charles Morin form:errors should work for java.util.Date too. Asking another question may help you.